# IONIC back title work in browser but not after build android application

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework

I make simple application using ionic with the jboss developer studio. I run the apps in browser during development after completing that i am build apps using command prompt using ionic build android and i am install in mobile phone now problem is occurs in top navbar back button is display but back name not display and title goes to left side.

```
<body ng-app="starter">
    <!--
      The nav bar that will be updated as we navigate between views.
    -->
    <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
      <ion-nav-back-button>
      </ion-nav-back-button>
    </ion-nav-bar>
    <!--
      The views will be rendered in the <ion-nav-view> directive below
      Templates are in the /templates folder (but you could also
      have templates inline in this html file if you'd like).
    -->
    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
  </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just experienced same problem as you.

add

```
$ionicConfigProvider.backButton.previousTitleText(true);
```

to the app.config section to solve this.